# How to remove the right border of the starter in unity?

Tags: unity, gui, customization

I was wondering if it's possible to remove the white border from the unity starter (the background of the starter is transparent, so the border is visible).

[image]

After searching around for a while I still haven't found a way to do this.

*Is this possible?*

Answer (score 0):

No, it cannot be removed

......